# Present Continuous with state verb "see"

Tags: present-continuous

I´ve passed some test and the quiestion was "We... our friends tonight" and answers "see, are seeing, are see". I chose "see" but the right is "are seeing". Isn´t it a mistake? if not, please, explaine the rule in short. thanks a lot

Comment: Refer this **[explanation](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/)**

Answer (score 2):

Many a times we use present continuous tense to talk about an event that has not happened yet, but happen in the future.

But you could argue then why is it called *'Present* Continues'?

Normally present continuous is used to talk about actions happening now, but if you add a *'future'* term, we can use it to refer an event from the future. These terms include words or expressions like tomorrow, tonight, next year.

For examples, please refer **[this link](https://learnenglishkids.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-practice/present-continuous-future-arrangements)** and **[this link](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/)**.

Answer (score 0):

The verb "see" in "We **are seeing** our friends tonight" is not stative, but dynamic. It is equivalent to "visit", and can therefore take the continuous form.

Besides, the present continuous can be used to express future plans or arrangements, as is the case here.